# C# using System.Linq error

Tags: c#, linq

Why might "using System.Linq" cause the following error?

> The type or namespace name 'Linq' does
>   not exist in the namespace 'System'

Comment: Which C# version are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual C# 2008, Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, .NET 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Reference `System.Core`

And then there are others that merge this namespace too - but that's the primary one *on .Net 3.5 and above*.

If you're project is currently .Net 2.0, say, and you're using the right version of VS (2005 and above) - you can simply right-click on the proejct properties; and change the 'Target Framework Version' to 3.5.  `System.Core` will then become available.

If you don't see that in the options - then I guess you're using an older VS

Comment: I don't see System.Core as an option in Right-click References > Add Reference.

Comment: Had to change Project > Properties > Application > Framework from 2.0 to 3.5

Comment: In that case you're probably writing a Net 2.0 or, even worse, 1.0-1 library. System.Core, as I say in my answer ***is 3.5 and above***

Comment: @JackN - I just updated my answer to say that exact same thing :)

Answer (score 5):

The most probable reason is that you are using wrong version of .NET Framework.

Comment: @takrl: Rather vote for @Andras Zoltan. He provided the most complex answer first.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add `System.Core` assembly to your project

Answer (score 4):

You'll get this error if you don't have "System.Core.dll" referenced (the assembly which contains the core LINQ APIs).

Answer (score 4):

System.Linq is available in .Net 3.5 and above version.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're targeting an older framework, Linq came in with 3.5 IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

You are using lower version of .NET Framework than 3.5 to compile the source code or you don't have added the System.Core assembly to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Manually type `using System.Linq` in the starting of the project, you will not be able to find this namespace in add reference dialogue box.
If you are still getting error then try to Add Reference `System.Core`.
If you are getting an error that it has been already referred then you can unload your project and then edit your csproject file, manually copy reference to `System` tag and paste and change the name to `System.Core` and reload the project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only thing that worked was:

#### Adding a new Razor item (e.g. MVC 5 View Page)

[image: Add new Razor item]

#### That automatically pulls in some NuGet packages

[image: installed NuGet packages]

<sub>The package that makes `System.Linq` available to Razor Views IntelliSense seems to be `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages`.</sub>