# can't import Linq using "using System.Linq;" in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have imported external website into visual studio 2015. I am using .net 4.8. I am having trouble to import system.linq. It is saying "the type or namespace does not exist in the namespace system". I dont know Why does it not exist even I am using .net 4.8.

I have also tried to update to visual studio 2019 but same error occurs

```
using DAL;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;   /// here error is showing
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using CsvHelper;
using System.Text;
```

the type or namespace does not exist in the namespace system

Comment: You need to add System.Linq as reference to your project. Adding a using at the top of a file doesn't automatically add the reference.

Comment: could you tell me how to add reference to the project?

Comment: System.Linq is part of .NET framework assemblies. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2017) a quick guide about how to add references to your project.

Comment: How did you import the site?

Comment: actullay I opened it from File->Open->Website

Comment: added it from reference manager but still facing same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# using System.Linq error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110540/c-sharp-using-system-linq-error)

Answer (score 1):

you have to Add System.Linq dll to your project

do this:

1. right click on `References` in your project from solution explorer
2. click on `Manage NuGet Packages`
3. search System.Linq then click on Install

Answer (score 0):

The System.Linq namespace is in the System.Core assembly (in System.Core.dll). 
So, it is needed to put system.core.dll in references.